# Masonic React.js: width scrolling issue with Left Nav

Tags: reactjs, masonry

[image]

```
import * as React from 'react';
    import {
      Card,
      CardBody,
      CardLink,
      CardImg,
      CardTitle,
      CardText,
    } from 'reactstrap';
    import {useWindowSize} from '@react-hook/window-size';
    import {
      useMasonry,
      usePositioner,
      useContainerPosition,
      useScroller,
    } from 'masonic';
    
    const Gallery = ({items}) => {
      const containerRef = React.useRef(null);
      let [windowWidth, height] = useWindowSize();
      windowWidth = windowWidth - (0.3*windowWidth);
      const {offset, width} = useContainerPosition(containerRef, [
        windowWidth,
        height,
      ]);
      const positioner = usePositioner({width, columnGutter: 8});
      const {scrollTop, isScrolling} = useScroller(offset);
    
      const NatureCard = ({
        index,
        data: {image = '', displayName, description = '', link = ''},
        width,
      }) => (
        <div>
          <Card>
            <CardImg src={image} />
            <CardTitle tag="h5">{displayName}</CardTitle>
            <CardText>{description}</CardText>
            {link && <CardLink href={link}>View</CardLink>}
          </Card>
        </div>
      );
    
      return (
        <div>
          {useMasonry({
            positioner,
            scrollTop,
            isScrolling,
            height,
            containerRef,
            items: items,
            overscanBy: 3,
            rowGutter: 10,
            render: NatureCard,
          })}
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Gallery;
```

I am using masonic and above code however my data is getting rearranged very weird across the width rather than the height

The library being used: https://codesandbox.io/s/masonryscroller-example-hb3qj

EDIT: I think the issue is with how I retrieve my items

CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/masonryscroller-example-hb3qj?file=/src/index.js

Comment: `<CardImg height="256" width="256" src={image} />` Yes, it does seem like the images are different sizes which is causing the issue. You can specify the dimensions.

Comment: I also suggest using 'react-masonry-component'. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-mclaren-ksfo1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) is the sandbox.

Comment: I have tried that as well @ParthShah didn't work

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the images are fetched by the browser the height of the cards change so their position should be recalculated. This is done using the `useResizeObserver` which creates a resize observer that forces updates to the grid cell positions when mutations are made to cells affecting their height. Now whenever you resize the component it will render correctly. There is another issue in initial render `width` is 0 so the items aren't positioned correctly. I used `windowWidth` as a placeholder until width is set.

You can check it here in the docs: https://github.com/jaredLunde/masonic#useresizeobserverpositioner

The asnwer [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/masonryscroller-example-5ite6?file=/src/index.js)

The answer:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useWindowSize } from "@react-hook/window-size";
import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardTitle } from "reactstrap";
import { styles } from "./theme";
import {
  useMasonry,
  usePositioner,
  useContainerPosition,
  useScroller,
  // import this
  useResizeObserver
} from "masonic";

const App = () => {
  const containerRef = React.useRef(null);
  let [windowWidth, windowHeight] = useWindowSize();
  const { offset, width } = useContainerPosition(containerRef, [
    windowWidth,
    windowHeight
  ]);
  // the width is equal to windowWidth - scroll bar width (17px in chrome)
  console.log(width, windowWidth);
  const positioner = usePositioner({
    // Use windowWidth as a placeholder if container width is 0 which causes positioning problems
    // This happens in initial render then width will be used
    width: width || windowWidth,
    columnGutter: 10
  });
  // This hook creates a resize observer that forces updates to the grid
  // cell positions when mutations are made to cells affecting their height.
  const resizeObserver = useResizeObserver(positioner);
  const { scrollTop, isScrolling } = useScroller(offset);

  return (
    <main>
      <div>
        {useMasonry({
          positioner,
          scrollTop,
          isScrolling,
          height: windowHeight,
          containerRef,
          items: items,
          render: NatureCard,
          // use it here
          resizeObserver
        })}
      </div>
      <Header />
    </main>
  );
};

const NatureCard = ({
  index,
  data: { image = "", displayName, description = "Hello", link = "" },
  width,
  height
}) => (
  <Card>
    <CardImg src={image} />
    <CardTitle tag="h5">{displayName}</CardTitle>
    <CardText>{description}</CardText>
  </Card>
);

const Header = () => {
  // const scrollY = useWindowScroll(5);
  return (
    <h1>
      <span role="img" aria-label="bricks">
        
      </span>{" "}
      MASONIC
    </h1>
  );
};

const items = [
  {
    image:
      "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/gettyimages-647727888-master-1506626232.jpg",
    displayName: "QUIZ: Has Reese Witherspoon Smooched These Guys On-Screen?"
  },
  {
    image:
      "https://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/320/cpsprodpb/97BE/production/_98064883_ikea.jpg",
    displayName: "Ikea buys odd jobs firm TaskRabbit"
  },
  {
    image:
      "https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/mt/2017/09/ra_3000x3000-4/facebook.jpg",
    displayName:
      "Radio Atlantic: Russia! Live with Julia Ioffe and Eliot A. Cohen"
  },
  {
    image: "https://i.redd.it/th5enkjgumoz.jpg",
    displayName: "Bar"
  },
  {
    image: "https://imgur.com/lvK8Faf.jpg",
    displayName:
      "'Cancer patient' finds lump was toy traffic cone inhaled in 1977 | UK news"
  },
  {
    image: "https://i.imgur.com/e89Pb8j.gif",
    displayName: "It's cool bro, I got this"
  },
  {
    image: "https://i.redd.it/336erdiy5moz.jpg",
    displayName: "Reddit"
  },
  {
    image:
      "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/img-5675-jpg-1506621753.jpg",
    displayName:
      "Prepare to Geek Out Over This Adorable Game of Thrones Wedding Shower"
  },
  {
    image:
      "https://venturebeat.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/ShopChat-e1506572472915.jpg",
    displayName: "Effective chatbots master conversational size and fit"
  },
  {
    image:
      "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/gettyimages-647727888-master-1506626232.jpg",
    displayName: "QUIZ: Has Reese Witherspoon Smooched These Guys On-Screen?"
  },
  {
    image:
      "https://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/320/cpsprodpb/97BE/production/_98064883_ikea.jpg",
    displayName: "Ikea buys odd jobs firm TaskRabbit"
  },
  {
    image:
      "https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/mt/2017/09/ra_3000x3000-4/facebook.jpg",
    displayName:
      "Radio Atlantic: Russia! Live with Julia Ioffe and Eliot A. Cohen"
  },
  {
    image: "https://i.redd.it/th5enkjgumoz.jpg",
    displayName: "Bar"
  },
  {
    image: "https://i.imgur.com/HjgUCHF.png",
    displayName:
      "'Cancer patient' finds lump was toy traffic cone inhaled in 1977 | UK news"
  },
  {
    image: "https://i.imgur.com/e89Pb8j.gif",
    displayName: "It's cool bro, I got this"
  },
  {
    image: "https://i.redd.it/336erdiy5moz.jpg?4",
    displayName: "Reddit"
  },
  {
    image:
      "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/img-5675-jpg-1506621753.jpg",
    displayName:
      "Prepare to Geek Out Over This Adorable Game of Thrones Wedding Shower"
  },
  {
    image:
      "https://venturebeat.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/ShopChat-e1506572472915.jpg",
    displayName: "Effective chatbots master conversational size and fit"
  },
  {
    image: "https://i.imgur.com/e89Pb8j.gif",
    displayName: "It's cool bro, I got this"
  },
  {
    image: "https://i.redd.it/336erdiy5moz.jpg?4",
    displayName: "Reddit"
  },
  {
    image:
      "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/img-5675-jpg-1506621753.jpg",
    displayName:
      "Prepare to Geek Out Over This Adorable Game of Thrones Wedding Shower"
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed i was able to achieve it

Answer (score -1):

I have take a look at your code sanbox and the one [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/usemasonry-example-3pcg9?file=/src/index.js:874-879), too.

Your problem is:

- If you use `useMasonry`, you **MUST** specify the `height` property for each item. You can see that in above example code sanbox, it generates random height for demo and use it to apply style for grid item via `style={{ height: props.data.height }}`.
- You you use `Masonry` component instead, you **MUST** specify the `columnWidth` property. In other words, this approach is just a kind of above one, just different from specifying `width` and `height`.

My working code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/masonryscroller-worked-example-0dsls?file=/src/index.js:2259-2270).

You can try to play around with two approach in my code sandbox to understand more. By the way, the `@-ui/react` library is **DEPRECATED** also.

I suggest another library you can investigate on is `bricks.js`: http://callmecavs.com/bricks.js/

Comment: This asnwer is wrong. You are using `Masonry` component which uses `useResizeObserver ` under the hood tha's why it's working. `height` is totally useless in your answer.

Comment: Have you taken a look at commented code below that `Mansory` component?

Comment: Using height is not like using `Masonary` component. `Masonary` component uses `useResizeObserver` under the hood that's why it's working. Setting height of `Card` with  `useMasonry` will just give the cards fixed height which is not optimal because the images has different heights and it's not known beforehand so the content will overflow the `Card`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AhmedMokhtar.
But first, I don't mean we should set `height` for image, because you know, image size is vary, I mean here is `height` for `Card`.
That's why I prefered fixed width approach in my solution instead.

Comment: Again as I told you height is useless in your example. it's not used automatically by the library to do anything. You must use it yourself. This is what the library author did himself in `useMasnory` example he used set the height explicitly in the card component

`const FakeCard = props => (
  <div className={style("card")} style={{ height: props.data.height }}>
    <span children={props.data.id} />
  </div>
); `